# How to convert HMAC_SHA256_MAC in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-4

index.php

```
<form class="row g-3" action="<?php echo base_url('signin'); ?>" method="post" id="loginForm" onsubmit="return hashpass();"> 
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
        <label for="inputChoosePassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="show_hide_password">
            <input type="password" class="form-control border-end-0" name="password" required id="password" value="12345678" placeholder="Enter Password"> <a href="javascript:;" class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class='bx bx-hide'></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="d-grid">
            <button type="submit" id="signin" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="hashpass();"><i class="bx bxs-lock-open"></i>Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/HmacSHA256.js"></script>
<script>
function hashpass(){
     var FormName='loginForm';
     document.forms[FormName]["password"].value=HMAC_SHA256_MAC("aSm0$i_20eNh3os", document.forms[FormName]["password"].value);
            return true;
 }
</script>
```

Home_Controller.php

```
public function signin()
    { 
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $uname = $this->request->getPost('uname');
        $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
        $data = $userModel->signin($uname);
        
        foreach($data as $key=>$value)
        {           
            $auth_id=$value->auth_id;
            $s_password=$value->password;
        }
        
        if(!empty($data))
        { 
            if(password_verify($password, $s_password))
            {   
                $session->set('auth_id',$auth_id);
                $this->response->redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
            }else{ 
                $this->response->redirect(base_url());
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $this->response->redirect(base_url());
        }
    }
```

If I get value from front end suppose value is *demo* enter from front end then get in controller If I print *$2y$10$nxdb2IIIu0QMcXH0T0q0buKcugSUNT3muDOmelBO.fjTE5D8OrICq*. So now without this script I want ***$2y$10$nxdb2IIIu0QMcXH0T0q0buKcugSUNT3muDOmelBO.fjTE5D8OrICq*** this output using PHP function.

Comment: HMAC is no encryption, it's a hash..

Comment: @Lars Stegelitz it was typed by mistake. i want same output like this script but in php. how its write

Answer (score 0):

Here is the php exmple.

```
<?php
echo hash_hmac('sha256', 'data', 'secret');
?>
```

Update the JS script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script>
function hashpass(){
     var FormName='loginForm';
     document.forms[FormName]["password"].value=CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(document.forms[FormName]["password"].value, "aSm0$i_20eNh3os");
            return true;
 }
</script>
```

You can check the link.
[Hash HMAC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

Comment: @S N Sharma try this function also but not same output like above script

Comment: @Aaditi share logic behind HMAC_SHA256_MAC function. I did not get it.

Comment: @S N Sharma Please check the post now hope u get my point

Comment: @Aaditi Uncaught ReferenceError: HMAC_SHA256_MAC is not defined

Comment: @S N Sharma now I add Script. Check now

Comment: @Aaditi check the updated answer. You have to update the JS script. I think this is you secret key 'aSm0$i_20eNh3os'

Comment: @S N Sharma  now I am doing it another page to password verify. database password =demo (which is store using this script then use `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  ` function then store in database. so now compare this database password and $password='demo'. so how its compare?

Comment: @Aaditi If you are trying to create a login, then you do not have to use the JS hashing on front end. Instead the encrypted password is already saved in database, you just only have to encrypt the password received from input field using php hasing, then compare both.